# Looking for an explanation of post/pre/set Translate (in Matrix object) and how to use them

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, android-canvas

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) is pretty vague as to what is actually happening when these methods are used.  Can someone explain how Matrix actually affects the Bitmap that it's being set to? They use the term concatenate in there, but I'm unclear on how that term applies to coordinate data (having only used it in regard to string manipulation before).

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The set-methods will replace the current Matrix with new values, disregarding whatever the Matrix contained before. The pre and post method will apply a new transformation before or after whatever the current Matrix contains.

In this example, the rotation will be ignored since we are using the set method and the m will only contain a translation:

> Matrix m = new Matrix();
>
> m.setRotate(90);
>
> m.setTranslate(100, 100);

In this example, the final matrix will be a translation followed by a rotation:

> Matrix m = new Matrix();
>
> m.setTranslate(100, 100);
>
> m.postRotate(90);

In the final example, the final matrix will be a rotation followed by a translation:

> Matrix m = new Matrix();
>
> m.setTranslate(100, 100);
>
> m.preRotate(90);

There is some more information in this (rather lengthy) post:

https://medium.com/a-problem-like-maria/understanding-android-matrix-transformations-25e028f56dc7

Hope it helps.

Comment: Some commentary on the coordinates it uses would be super in this answer too. e.g "a rotation followed by a translation" is fairly obvious : but how does it achive this in terms of the x & y axis? How to rotate something about its central point and not the coordinate root.

Comment: The question was about the difference between the pre/post/set methods. The api docs are rather clear about the different variants of each transformation. There is of course some consequence to the parameter values when you apply the transformations in different orders, but that's a bit off topic here.

Comment: This helps alot, I think so much that the Android Developing team should include it in their docs.

Comment: Link is out-dated. Use this one: https://medium.com/a-problem-like-maria/understanding-android-matrix-transformations-25e028f56dc7

Comment: @Albin Unlike the set methods, pre and post methods return a boolean value, and the docs do not mention what that is and what it means, any ideas?

Comment: @SMMH Not sure, but I guess it signifies if the combination was successful or not. I think the relevant code can be found here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/skia/+/76f9e93/src/core/SkMatrix.cpp#634