# Android matrix manipulation

Tags: java, android, matrix, bitmap

I have a question regarding matrix manipulation on canvases. I *think* I understand what is happening, but I would like someone to confirm for me. I have scoured the internet for the past hour and a half and can't seem to find specifically what I'm looking for.  My question is: In the below lines of code, before the bitmap is drawn, it is rotated about its center point by 'angle' degrees, then placed on the canvas at (100, 100), correct? I'm developing a game where I need certain objects to rotate according to another's position, and everything is working perfectly, I just want to know exactly what I'm doing. Any confirmation/clarification is welcome. :)

```
matrix.setRotate(angle, 0, 0);
matrix.postTranslate(100, 100);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is exactly what's happening.  No need to scour the net, just look at the [Java Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html).  Also there's a nice description of `postTranslate` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197656/looking-for-an-explanation-of-post-pre-set-translate-in-matrix-object-and-how).

Comment: i agree and if you (i mean OP) want to use this matrix to change the whole canvas you can call canvas.concat(matrix)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also looked the java documentation and while there is a good bit of information on this topic, I couldn't find exactly what I needed. Thanks again.